# How long is the delay between IFTTT trigger and posting action?

Tags: if-this-then-that

How long does it take for IFTTT to notice that a trigger has occurred and for IFTTT to fire off the event? The IFTTT website is absent of any documentation.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Most Personal Recipes check for new Trigger data every 15 minutes, some are even faster.

via their [learn more page](http://ifttt.com/wtf)

Comment: Gah. I didn't scroll all the way to the bottom when I was looking at that page. Thanks.

Comment: cheers @RHPT, happens to the best of us.

Comment: Are you sure it is every 15 minutes? I created an `event` 36 minutes ago which should have caused a trigger but nothing happened.

Comment: Seems to take a little longer sometimes. I bet 15 minutes is an average or an estimate.

Comment: The answer above is wrong. SMS (texting your IFTTT number) takes only 4 seconds to trigger. Phone (calling your IFTTT number) takes 4 seconds to trigger. Date and Time (IFTTT clock) is accurate down to the minute. For those interested in the wrong answer see above. For those interested in the correct answer see: [How long is the delay between ifttt trigger and posting action?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/59930)

Comment: @sathya this answer is wrong. Please remove it as it is deceiving people.

Comment: @AaronKlap it's not wrong. They mention some are polled faster, some aren't.

Comment: @sathya When someone looks for the time it takes for a trigger to initiate a task, they probably want to know the ACTUAL time it takes for a trigger to initiate a task. Regurgitating the companies BS is probably not what they are looking for. Have you actually used this service before? If you have, then why don't you give the correct answer?

Comment: @AaronKlap for it to trigger, it needs to check that there's something to trigger. Also, https://ifttt.com/p/sathyabhat I'm not "Regurgitating the companies(sic) BS". I'm pointing to their official documentation.

Comment: @sathya 15 minutes is not correct by any stretch of the imagination. I have tested the SMS and Phone call triggers which only take four seconds to trigger a task (+/- two seconds). I have repeated this experiment using two different pieces of hardware and in numerous locations. I see you have not shared either of these two triggers so perhaps you are simply ignorant (as I hope you are not purposefully trying to deceive people). If you would like, I could post these experiments on YouTube clearly showing your answer is wrong (or you could try using them yourself).

Comment: @AaronKlap there are a _lot_ more triggers than SMS & Phone calls. The fact that SMS/calls trigger faster, I've edited my answer to reflect. There's no 'deception'. Feel free to downvote my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14663/discussion-between-aaron-klap-and-sathya).

Comment: @user18015 If you have had some take longer, them please add them to the list here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/59930/21622

Comment: @Travis Pflanz If you have had some take longer, them please add them to the list here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/59930/21622

Answer (score 12):

This varies depending on the type of channel being used.

Although the [official answer](https://ifttt.com/wtf) is that

> tasks poll for new trigger data every 15 minutes.

anyone who has actually used their service will know this is obviously wrong in many cases. Here is what I have found for the time it takes for the trigger to initiate the task:

1. SMS (texting your IFTTT number) - 4 seconds, nearly instant.
2. Twitter - 10 minutes to 15 minutes.
3. Phone (calling your IFTTT number) - 4 seconds, nearly instant.
4. Date and Time (IFTTT clock) - accurate down to the minute.

Feel free to add to this list over time.

15 minutes = 900 seconds. Percent error = (stated value - actual value) / actual value * 100%. If you relied on the value of 15 minutes for the phone response time then the percent error would be (900-4)/4*100% = 22,400%. 22,400% error is a very large error! The 15 minute response time can be very inaccurate.

I noticed that after a month, an android trigger occurred, but the IFTTT site listed it as not occurring. This has happened to me for two recipes involving my android phone. How I solved this was to uninstall the IFTTT app on my android phone, then remove the android channel, then install the IFTTT application on my android phone again, and activate the channel. After performing these steps the triggers started "triggering" again.

Comment: SMS & Phone definitely don't work like that anymore... unless it's the newness of the account, the recipe, or the channel activation that's making them take their time (I just set up everything just today).

I've been waiting over an hour for text & voicemail alerts to automatically trigger, though if I manually hit the "Refresh" button on the recipe itself the text (sent over 30 minutes ago) will generate the desired action. I haven't yet seen it automatically trigger based on a phone call or a text message.

Answer (score 7):

Tasks do poll for trigger data **every 15 minutes** [officially](https://ifttt.com/wtf), but there's some nuance to this that might be helpful to people who don't work with web services.

1. *Polling* means requesting new info periodically.
2. Every IFTTT recipe has two sides - the *If This* (trigger) side, and the *Then That*
   (action) side.
3. The trigger represents the search for something to
   *trigger* the recipe.
4. The action represents what IFTTT does in response to the trigger.
5. Polling every 15 minutes means that the
   trigger data will be checked that often, but says nothing about the
   action time, which starts nearly immediately (although I expect
   actions get queued to manage server load)

Comment: Good answer! Could you add a link to where it says that polls are done every 15 minutes?

Answer (score 0):

RSS feed updated through Yahoo Pipes gathering data from Google Spreadsheet CSV collecting Google Form responses.

IFTTT Recipe: RSS Feed new item triggers Gmail send message.

Google Spreadsheet updates immediately after form submission and publishes to web.
Yahoo Pipes updates CSV within 60 seconds and presents valid RSS feed.
2 hours in, IFTTT still not triggering - even after manual check.

I would say the action is based on server load and queueing. 15 minutes for a trigger check is bunk I'm finding.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are going for here?  Are you adding additional information or just corroborating the other answers?

Comment: @user70846 Thank you for the answer. Glad to see others know the 15 minute trigger time is bogus in most cases.