# IFTTT Twitter DM recipe not always firing

Tags: if-this-then-that, twitter-integration

I have several IFTTT recipes that are supposed to send a DM - every time I add or read something in Pocket for instance.

I'm finding that the recipe fires every time but the DM doesn't always get created in Twitter. Is IFTTT or Twitter limiting the number of DMs that can be created in a short space of time? I know there is a 250 DM limit per day, but I'm not getting near this.

[I know about the 15 minute window](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22484/how-long-is-the-delay-between-ifttt-trigger-and-posting-action), but I would expect that perhaps the tweets get sent in bulk every 15 minutes. If I refresh the IFTTT web interface it is saying that the recipe is being triggered each time as expected. Am I misunderstanding how IFTTT works?

Comment: Seems like it should be working to me. I think you should contact the IFTTT people directly. This sounds like it might be a bug. In my experience they're pretty responsive.

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: No, the recipes are still up and work but not massively reliable.